How to create two or more \tcolorboxenvironment for the same environment?
I have created a
 \proof

environment with
 \tcolorboxenvironment, 

according to the following preamble and code snippet:
   \documentclass{report}
   \usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
   \usepackage[table, dvipsnames,x11names]{xcolor}
   \usepackage{afterpage} 
   \usepackage{titlesec}
   \usepackage{amssymb, amsthm, amsmath, amscd}
   \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
   \usepackage{mathtools}
   \usepackage{xpatch}
   \usepackage[most,many,breakable]{tcolorbox}
   \usepackage{graphicx}
   \usepackage{lipsum}

   \definecolor{mylightgray}{RGB}{191, 191, 191}

   \tcbuselibrary{theorems,skins,hooks, most}

   \xpatchcmd{\proof}{\itshape}{\color{blue}\bfseries\scshape}{}{}

   \tcolorboxenvironment{proof}{
   fonttitle=\bfseries\bcshape,
   enhanced,
   top=0mm,
   boxrule=0pt,frame hidden,
   borderline west={5pt}{0pt}{mylightgray},%
   borderline east={5pt}{0pt}{mylightgray},
   coltitle=blue,
   colback=white,
   breakable,
   sharp corners
   }

   \begin{document}
   \begin{proof}
   \lipsum[1]
   \end{proof}
   \end{document}

I would like to create several
      \tcolorboxenvironment{proof} 

identical to this one, with borderlines in different colors and so that one can refer to the different proof environments in the text.
How to do that? I had tried with some methods like [auto counter], but without success.

I am a bit confused, what relates the border color with the need to auto-number the environments to refer to them later?

@Rmano Maybe I explained myself badly. I would like various proof colorboxes of different colors because I would like to differentiate them according to colors: Theorem's proof with a borderline color, Lemma's proof with another borderline color, Claim's proof with another borderline color, and so on...

Your example does not work, because of using a not defined color. Please always try to make your example compilable → https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/277964.

Have a look at \NewTcbTheorem to create a bunch of different theorem environments.

@cabohah Yes, you're right. I'm editing the original answer so that the MWE can be compilable.

The coloredtheorem package might be interesting for you

Your proof environments are not numbered, so I don't know what you mean with your second question about refering to them. But because you should never mix several questions into one, I would recommend to ask the second question as a new question and answer only the first one.
LaTeX provides \NewEnvironmentCommand to copy an environment. You can use this to define several proof… environments with different tcolorbox options:
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[table, dvipsnames,x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage[most,many,breakable]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\tcbuselibrary{theorems,skins,hooks, most}

\xpatchcmd{\proof}{\itshape}{\color{blue}\bfseries\scshape}{}{}

\NewEnvironmentCopy{proofgray}{proof}
\tcolorboxenvironment{proofgray}{
  fonttitle=\bfseries\bcshape,
  enhanced,
  top=0mm,
  boxrule=0pt,frame hidden,
  borderline west={5pt}{0pt}{lightgray},%
  borderline east={5pt}{0pt}{lightgray},
  coltitle=blue,
  colback=white,
  breakable,
  sharp corners
}

\NewEnvironmentCopy{proofred}{proof}
\tcolorboxenvironment{proofred}{
  fonttitle=\bfseries\bcshape,
  enhanced,
  top=0mm,
  boxrule=0pt,frame hidden,
  borderline west={5pt}{0pt}{red},%
  borderline east={5pt}{0pt}{red},
  coltitle=blue,
  colback=white,
  breakable,
  sharp corners
}

\begin{document}
\begin{proofgray}
  \lipsum[1]
\end{proofgray}
\lipsum[2]
\begin{proofred}
  \lipsum[3]
\end{proofred}

\end{document}


Note: Assumed, that the different proof… environments have different meaning, I would suggest to not use a name like proofgray or proofred but to use a kind of semantic name like importantproof, secondlevelproof etc.
You can use a copied version of proof also to define a more general version, that uses an additional argument for the color:
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[table, dvipsnames,x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage[most,many,breakable]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\tcbuselibrary{theorems,skins,hooks, most}

\xpatchcmd{\proof}{\itshape}{\color{blue}\bfseries\scshape}{}{}

\NewEnvironmentCopy{Proof}{proof}

\RenewDocumentEnvironment{proof} {m} {%
  \tcolorbox[{savedelimiter=proof,
      fonttitle=\bfseries\bcshape,
      enhanced,
      top=0mm,
      boxrule=0pt,frame hidden,
      borderline west={5pt}{0pt}{#1},
      borderline east={5pt}{0pt}{#1},
      coltitle=blue,
      colback=white,
      breakable,
      sharp corners,
    }]
  \Proof
}{%
  \endProof
  \endtcolorbox
}

\begin{document}
\begin{proof}{lightgray}
  \lipsum[1]
\end{proof}

\lipsum[2]

\begin{proof}{red}[Superproof]
  \lipsum[3]
\end{proof}

\end{document}


Here, I've also demonstrated, that the optional argument to proof is still supported.
Note: \tcolorboxenvironment cannot be used to add new arguments to an existing environment. So if you still want to use proof as environment name, IMHO using \renewenvironment, \RenewDocumentEnvironment, \renewtcolorbox, \renewtcbtheorem etc. is needed to change the supported arguments to the environment.

Thank you, this is very close to what I was looking for. The most immediate solution would be @DavidCarlisle's, but I can't understand why it doesn't work. Anyway, +1.
